# Network plugin ngCodova don't work into controller

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I am using a plugin to get the status and connection type my mobile device through an application. But the plugin only works within `$ionicPlatform.ready`, at least that happened to me, when I run into the controller, the result of the type of connection is `unknow`.

Plugin link: [Network Plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/network/)
Installer link: [CLI installer](http://cordova%20plugin%20add%20cordova-plugin-network-information)

#### Code

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
    .run(startApp)
    .controller('networkCtrl', networkCtrl);

startApp.$inject = ['$ionicPlatform', '$cordovaNetwork'];

function startApp($ionicPlatform, $cordovaNetwork) {

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
        }

        if (window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }

        var netInfo;
        netInfo = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork();
        console.log(netInfo); //wifi, 4G, 3G, etc.

    });

}

networkCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$cordovaNetwork'];

function networkCtrl($scope, $cordovaNetwork) {

    var netInfo;
    netInfo = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork();
    console.log(netInfo); //unknow

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this inside   `document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {`

```
function networkCtrl($scope, $cordovaNetwork) {
    $scope.networkType = null;
    $scope.connectionType = null;
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
      $scope.networkType = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork();
      if ($cordovaNetwork.isOnline()) {
        $scope.connectionType = 'Online';
      }
      else if ($cordovaNetwork.isOffline()) {
        $scope.connectionType = 'Offline';
      }
      else {
        $scope.errorMsg = 'Error getting isOffline / isOnline methods';
      }
    }, false);
 });
```

Comment: Ok, i try this, i will back

Comment: Work perfect, thanks, i add click event with ng-click, for get network information when try login without internet.